# mac OS zsh: getting warning on using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

So my new macbook came with preinstalled python(2.7.16), python3(3.8.2) and pip3(it was some 19.xx version). All these were preinstalled in `usr/bin/` and `pip` command was not recognized but `pip3` was working. I used the command `pip3 install --upgrade pip` to upgrade pip3. But now instead whenever I use the command `pip3 --version` command it gives me the following warning

> WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail
> in a future version of pip. Please see
> https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the
> underlying issue. To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m
> pip' instead of running pip directly. pip 21.1.3 from
> /Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip
> (python 3.8)

I think now pip is being called from the pip package in python3 site packages. I can use `python3 -m pip --version` command without any warning. I don't want to use `python3 -m` everytime.

So do I need to add some path variable?
What about the pip3 package that came preinstalled in `usr/bin` instead of pip in python3 site packages? How do I upgrade that and use it?

I need to install tensorflow with virtualenv. How do I solve the pip error?

Comment: Don’t use the system python.

Comment: Then how do I install the latest python (python and python3 both command work with system preinstalled python in usr/bin/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using macOS and python. Down the road, you will need to use newer version of python instead of the old one provided by system anyway. I will suggest you to use `homebrew` package manager for macOS and install latest python using `brew` command like `brew install python`. `brew` will install python and pip in `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin` path. You just need to add this path to your system path. Then you should have no issue to use `python` and `pip` command.

Comment: Can I not directly upgrade python3 that came preinstalled in usr/bin/

Comment: It's not a good idea to upgrade the system python because there might be many other system software depend on the system python. And it might be a problem when you do macOS upgrade as well.